# splitting an string into a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a quick question, I have the below df

df

```
    File_Path
0   /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh
1   /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh
2   /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3   /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing
4   sh /data/processos/current/aplicacao/AAVR/ACN10/scr/exec_fim_grupo.sh ACN10_ARQ_1
```

and I want to get the 4th item of the tree structure in the File_Path column.

the output should looks like this:

df

```
    File_Path                                                                                                       Parent_path
0   /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
1   /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
2   /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh                                                                     /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3   /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh                             /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/
4   sh /data/processos/current/aplicacao/AAVR/ACN10/scr/exec_fim_grupo.sh ACN10_ARQ_1                               /data/processos/current/aplicacao/
```

In index = 2, there is no 4th item, so it gets the last, which is a file call_nba_as11.sh

Also in index=4 there is a "sh " in the begining of the file_path value, I need to escape that

could guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Parent_path'] = df['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')
```

output:

```
                                                                                                        File_Path                                           Parent_path
0  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh    /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
1  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh    /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
2                                                                     /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh           /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3                    /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing  /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SVIha/1)

Alternative:

```
df['Parent_path'] = df['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')
```

Output:

```
                                                                                                        File_Path                                           Parent_path
0  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_INVE_D.sh    /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
1  /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/scripts/s_shell/call_iws/call_PP_NEXT_RTBA_MAU_IND_EMPF_D.sh    /data/application/AANX/aanx-dataeng-slas-sysyphus/
2                                                                     /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh           /data/app_next_best_action/call_nba_as11.sh
3                    /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/iws/call_run_extract_default.sh cdlc_ing  /data/application/AAIN/aain-srv-motor-extracao-next/
4                               sh /data/processos/current/aplicacao/AAVR/ACN10/scr/exec_fim_grupo.sh ACN10_ARQ_1                    /data/processos/current/aplicacao/
```

Comment: hey @mozway, thanks for this, that almost nailed it, but there are command where the sh from the shell is coming first, like :
sh /data/processos/current/aplicacao/AAVR/ACN10/scr/exec_processo.sh ACN10_ARQ_1 PP_AAVRACN10_STAGE_C0001_03_D

for these cases, the outuput is blank, how could I escape this sh in the beggining of the string?

Comment: Use `r'^([^/]*(?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)'` as regex

Comment: mozway, may I ask why you used a non-capturing group in your regex?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR to be able to repeat up to 4 times the '/' followed by non-/ characters without capturing those subpatterns

Comment: @gfernandes actually if you don't want to capture the leading 'sh ': `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)'

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the concept of non-capturing group, but I don't quite get it what would happen if we omit `?:` here.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, why don't you try and see? ;) (NB. don't assign to a column)

Comment: I just did :) . In fact it leads to the same result we just capture more groups. So in this case `df['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^((/[^/]+){,4}/?)')[0]` could lead to the same output.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR but creating more columns is expensive, so not worth it if you're going to thrown them away immediately by slicing!

Comment: hey @mozway, I might be doing something wrong, getting syntax error, I got your last piece of code and tried to accomodate it in your fisrt suggestion:

which gave me this :
df['Parent_path'] = df['File_Path'].str.extract('sh ': `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')

Comment: Yes, the syntax is invalid. What did you try to accommodate?

Comment: this : 'sh ': `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)'

in this : df['Parent_path'] = df['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')

Comment: You are absolutely right. At this stage I was just trying to get it work. Your solution is top. Happy coding and happy following mozway where he posts an answer haha :))

Comment: @gfernandes DId you want `r'^(?:sh\s*)?((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)`, although `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)` should also work fine

Comment: your first suggestion would work, but in my data, there are sh command calling the the sh file in the file_path collumn, so, it giving me blank outputs, so I need to "escape" the sh when it is present, did you get it?

Comment: Yes and I provided alternatives for this in the comments one to keep the sh, one to drop the sh please read again and test them. I believe `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)` is what you want

Comment: yes, but I didn't get that, I tried the 3 suggestions you sent
1 - df_test["Parent_path"] = df_test['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)') #worked but didn't "treat" the sh in the begining
2 - df_test["Parent_path"] = df_test['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^([^/]*(?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)') #worked but didn't "treat" the sh in the begining
3 - df_test["Parent_path"] = df_test['File_Path'].str.extract('sh ': `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)') # i got syntax error 
                                                                     ^

Comment: Please update your question with a 'sh' example, we might be talking about different things

Comment: Also I don't know why you did `df_test['File_Path'].str.extract('sh ': `r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')`, I never suggested that (the syntax is invalid). Just do `df_test['File_Path'].str.extract(r'^[^/]*((?:/[^/]+){,4}/?)')`

Comment: I edited my post, please, have a look what I added in my df, index 4

Comment: See my update, this is what I've been telling you all that time :p